# ActionController::Parameters permitted assigned with field is nil in Model : Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am migrating code from Rails 3 to Rails 5.1.6 and Ruby 2.5. I am facing strange issue. I have written `after_initialize` callback in model and assigning default value to field. The field is `serialize` and when there is `nil` in that field it will assign default value inside the callback.

Here is my code for clear picture

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :settings

  after_initialize :set_default_setting

  def set_default_setting
    self.settings = self.settings || {my_fields: ["a", "b", "c"]}
  end
end
```

Here is my Rails console log :

```
[1] 2.5.0 :135 > md = MyModel.find(1)
=> #<MyModel:0x00007fe433608348
 id: 1,
 settings: <ActionController::Parameters  permitted: >,
 created_at: Tue, 16 Jan 2018 08:45:26 GMT +00:00,
 updated_at: Fri, 04 May 2018 10:50:20 BST +01:00>

[2] 2.5.0 :136 > md.settings
=> <ActionController::Parameters  permitted: >
[3] 2.5.0 :137 > md.settings.nil?
=> false
```

My question is why `<ActionController::Parameters  permitted: >` is being added in to nil field ? when I execute `nil?` method it should return me `nil`. Above code was working fine with Rails 3.2 and Ruby 2.0 from which I am upgrading to Rails 5 and Ruby 2.5

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: `self.settings = self.settings || {my_fields: ["a", "b", "c"]}` can be written as `self.settings ||= {my_fields: ["a", "b", "c"]}` btw.

Comment: Got it. Thank you..

Comment: That's strange behaviour, are you sure you haven't set `<ActionController::Parameters  permitted: >` before via assigning params? What `MyModel.new` returns?

Comment: When I tried MyModel.new it woks fine. I have checked records in database, and it seems you are correct, the value was set as `<ActionController::Parameters  permitted: >` but I can't confirm that how it was assigned and goes to database. This is important to know for me as in couple of places I have used callback like this. Any hint ?

Comment: Check the model, or some custom validations / before save callbacks. Probably you are assigning the reponse of some function to the settings attribute.